# Convert REST url in javascript literal

Tags: javascript

I want to convert a REST style url into a javascript literal, like this:

from:

```
var url = "/a/b/c/d";
```

to:

```
var obj = {
   a:{
     b:{
       c:{
         d:{}
       }
     }
   }
};
```

How would you do this?

Comment: Duplicate of [Javascript: How to set object property given its string name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719593/javascript-how-to-set-object-property-given-its-string-name)...it's basically the same, just the delimiter is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My attempt:

```
var url = '/a/b/c/d';
var fun = function(a) {  
  var res = {};
  res[a[0]] = a.length == 1 ? {} : fun(a.slice(1));
  return res;
};

// obj has what you need
var obj = fun(url.split('/').slice(1));    


// OTHER EXAMPLE
var t = ['that', 'is', 'so', 'fun'];
console.log(fun(t));
// above returns object: {that: { is: { so: { fun: {} }}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can probably condense it but here's a solution :

```
var u = '/a/b/c/d';
var t = u.split('/');
var o = {};
for (var i=t.length; i-->1; ) {
  var temp = o;
  o = {};
  o[t[i]] = temp;
}
```

The result is `o`.

Comment: I see no clean and fast way to remove the use of a temp variable :\

Comment: Had a go at editing the code to speed it up but you may find your version neater.

Comment: One way to remove use of `temp` is this, though probably not quicker: `o = (function () { return JSON.parse('{"' + t[i] + '": ' + JSON.stringify(o) + '}') })();`

Comment: I've rejected your edit. There was no reason for it to make a faster code.

Comment: @guypursey I thought about JSON and about eval. That's why I precised "clean and fast" in my comment.