# Change value in json object based on other key value

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json like as follow

```
[{
    "name": "abc",
    "Path": "i.abc",
    "count": 5347,
    "subFolders": []
},
{
    "name": "cde",
    "Path": "i.cde",
    "count": 0,
    "subFolders": [{
        "name": "efg",
        "Path": "",
        "count": 0,
        "subFolders": []
    },
    {
        "name": "hij",
        "Path": "i.hij",
        "count": 1,
        "subFolders": []
    }]
}]
```

I want to change "count" value based on "path"(its unique) value.
For example I want to change count as 2 for path "i.hij" like that.
Following is the code i have tried.

```
var json = "above json";
  for (i=0; i < json.length; i++) {
      this.updateJson(json[i], path, count);
  }

  updateJson: function(json, path, count) {

    if (json.path == path) {
        json.count = count;
        return json;
    } 

    if (json.subFolders != null && json.subFolders.length > 0) {

      for(j=0; j < json.subFolders.length; j++) {

          this.updateJson(json.subFolders[j], path, count);
      }
    }
  }
```

How do i get the whole json with modified value?

Comment: Your code appears to be incomplete (the `updateJson: function(json, path, count) {` at this position is strange). Also, the "problem" doesn't seem to have anything to do with JSON at all.

Comment: Your `json` variable appears to be a JS object, not a JSON string. Please name it in a less confusing way.

Comment: duplicate of [Javascript: How to set object property given its string name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13719593/218196).

Comment: @FelixKling As OP's code was not so far from the goal, I made an answer. It's probably better for him, in fact, than copying an already made code, especially as he has a `Path` field in his nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a few problems in your code, mainly you were confusing `Path` and `path` (JavaScript is case sensitive) and you were missing the `var` keyword in the `for` (this one is subtle and very dangerous), but you weren't that far from the goal.

Here's a fixed function :

```
var obj = [{
    "name": "abc",
    "Path": "i.abc",
    "count": 5347,
    "subFolders": []
},
{
    "name": "cde",
    "Path": "i.cde",
    "count": 0,
    "subFolders": [{
        "name": "efg",
        "Path": "",
        "count": 0,
        "subFolders": []
    },
    {
        "name": "hij",
        "Path": "i.hij",
        "count": 1,
        "subFolders": []
    }]
}];

function upd(o, path, count) {
  if (o.Path == path) {
        o.count = count;
  } else {
    var arr;
    if (Array.isArray(o)) arr = o;
    else if (o.subFolders) arr = o.subFolders;
    else return;
    for(var j=0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        upd(arr[j], path, count);
    }
  }
}
upd(obj, "i.hij", 3);
console.log(obj);
```

I also changed the variable names to remove all references to JSON, as there's no JSON here.

Comment: thanks for the code, but it is not terminating when i used the path "i.abc"

Comment: @user1606656 You're right, there was another bug (the `var` keyword in the `for` was missing). Fixed.