# Set a default value for a nested object property using the pipe symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, nested-attributes

For a given hash:

```
var hash = {
    a: "one",
    b: { cat: "two" }
};
```

Using two pipes `||` allowing to place an alternative value if one doesn't defined:

```
var number = hash.a || "just a number";  // -> "one"
var number = hash.c || "just a number";  // -> "just a number"
```

However, targeting the nested hash will result an error: `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`:

```
var number = hash.c.dog || "just a number";  // -> Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

**My question** is how to target a nested hash and set a default value as we're doing with a 'plain' hash?

Comment: related: [Javascript: How to set object property given its string name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13719593/218196), maybe this gives you an idea.

Comment: @FelixKling Interesting... of course building a function for that task is possible however I wonder if there's a better way?!

Comment: Well, there is no built-in way if that's what you mean. If you want to test whether a nested property exists, you have to test the existence of every "intermediate" property as well.

Comment: You're right. it is getting complicated as hash getting deeper. I'll give it more chance, maybe someone will come up with a creative idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript provides no special syntax for this. You need to test each potentially undefined value before assuming it's defined and trying to access one of its members.

You can still use `||` or `&&` for this, but in a non-trivial case, it's probably better to just use an `if`.

Using `||`:

```
var hash = {
    a: "one",
    b: { cat: "two" }
};

var x = (hash.c || {}).cat
```

Using `&&`:

```
var x = hash && hash.c && hash.c.cat
```

Comment: You're probably right, JS doesn't have special syntax for those cases (as mention by Felix Kling as well). Thanks for the advise.