# Changing attributes in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects (of arbitrary depth) with identical attributes:

```
var array = [],
    i;

for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    array.push({
        'a': '0',
        'b': {
            'c': '0'
        }
    });
}
```

I would like a function to set an attribute to a specific value in all objects like this:

```
// only to demonstrate, doesn't actually work!
function set(array, attribute, value) {
    array.forEach(function(obj) {
        obj[attribute] = value;
    });
}
```

To be able to use it like this (or similar):

```
set(array, 'a', 1);
set(array, 'b.c', 5);
```

If you're having trouble understanding my question please help me clarify. Thank you in advance!

## Solution

I solved it but couldn't post an answer so here it is:

```
function set(array, attribute, value) {
    // a.b.c => [a, b, c]
    attribute = attribute.split('.');

    array.forEach(function(obj) {
        // obj = array[index]
        for (i = 0; i < attribute.length - 1; i++) {
            // i = 0) obj = array[index].a
            //     1) obj = array[index].a.b
            obj = obj[attribute[i]];
        }

        // array[index].a.b.c = value
        obj[attribute[i]] = value;
    });
}
```

Comment: so what is the problem you face?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/13719593/1529630

Comment: I couldn't post an answer so I put my solution in the question for now.

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [],
    i;

for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    array.push({
        'a': '0',
        'b': {
            'c': '0'
        }
    });
}

set = function(array, key, value){
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    array[i][key] = value;
  }
}

set(array, "test", "Test");
alert(array[0]['test']);
```

Hah, @Oriol is right, you just have a syntax error on your original funciton.

Comment: That doesn't work for `b.c`