# Update value in an object when all you have is a string of the keys in dot notation?

Tags: javascript

```
// I have an object

var obj = {

  customerInfo: {
    firstName: "sdafsd",
    lastName: "sdfsdaf",
  }

}

// I'm provided with a string:

var string = "customerInfo.firstName";

// This obviously won't work for updating the value

obj[string] = "Bob";
```

The new value of `obj`

```
var obj = {

  customerInfo: {
    firstName: "sdafsd",
    lastName: "sdfsdaf",
  },

  "customerInfo.firstName": "Bob"

}
```

I took a look at Underscore but it appears that it doesn't have anything for updating a value in an object provided the key is a string.

Comment: Even better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13719593/218196

Comment: Yikes. Is there a "best" way out of all the answers?

Comment: Usually the more upvotes the better, no?

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny: the best is not to use dots in identifier

Comment: I know there are other answers. But to make it simple for your question, you might want to try `obj[string.split('.')[0]][string.split('.')[1]] = "Bob";`

Comment: @Felix Kling, no, I don't believe so. Not necessarily at least.