# find if path exists in json nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I would like to add to the an existing json a new value in the following path:

VAL:`"BS"`,  PATH:`["info", "bosses", "lives"]`

if my json had the passes it will add the value, otherwise I will create the fields

example:

```
var myJson = {
    "root": {
        "name": "jim",
        "age": "4",
        "info": {"bosses": {"name": "sam"}}
    }
}
```

so my new json will look like this:

```
 var myNewJson = {
    "root": {
        "name": "jim",
        "age": "4",
        "info": {"bosses": {"name": "sam", "lives": "BS"}}
    }
}
```

---

an example when I didn't have the fields:

```
var myJson = {
        "root": {
            "name": "jim",
            "age": "4",
        }
    }
```

the output:

```
var myNewJson = {
        "root": {
            "name": "jim",
            "age": "4",
            "info": {"bosses": {"lives": "BS"}}
        }
    }
```

---

an example where part of the path exists I didn't have the fields:

```
var myJson = {
        "root": {
            "name": "jim",
            "age": "4",
          "info": {"salary": 500}
        }
    }
```

the output:

```
var myNewJson = {
        "root": {
            "name": "jim",
            "age": "4",
            "info": {"salary": 500, "bosses": {"lives": "BS"}}
        }
    }
```

how can I check if path exists (note: part of the path might exist- how can I know from where to start it?)

Comment: ```if (myJson.root['info']) {
   /* code */
}```

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13719799/3284355 although they use string like `path='info.bosses.lives"` you can use it like this `assign(myJson, PATH, VAL);` since the path variable can also be array.

Comment: This could be good, but what if your attribute/field has 0 (zero) value? If you check path.to.your.node it will be false:

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but...
testing existence of fields on paths is nicer now, with [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), like:
`var infoExists = !!myJson?.root?.info` - the `?.` means that if root were missing, the line wouldn't break.

In this case though, I wouldn't worry about testing for the existence of fields, I'd use spread operators to just rebuild the `info` object:

```
var newInfo = {"bosses": {"lives": "BS"}};
var info = {...myJson.root.info, ...newInfo};
```

if `myJson.root.info` doesn't exist, no problem (as long as myJson.root does, cue an optional chaining check?), we just get the `newInfo`.

if `myJson.root.info` currently holds `{"salary": 500}`, the spread operators will combine that to `"info":{"salary": 500, "lives": "BS"}`.

if `myJson.root.info` currently holds the same as `newInfo`, well, no sweat, we end up with no change.

Now you have the info object exactly as you want it, you can simply replace it in the original object with
`myJson.root.info = ...info;`

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you could think it works could be some code like:

```
if (myObject.attributeName){
    //property exists!
}
```

It will work for you in many tests but I sure you know that javascript manage some values as truthy or falsy. It use lot's of different type value as boolean false in many comparison (just === not convert type).
When you check something as

```
if(somethingtotest){
// it's true
}
```

It is the same you'd write

```
if(somethingtotest == true){
// it's true
}
```

'==' operator tryes to convert different types to be "similar" together.
In the first example code many of object attribute values can be '==' true.
That attribute value is truthy, meaning it’s an object, a non-empty string, a non-zero number that’s not NaN, true, and not null or undefined. 
That means if the attribute is an empty string (“”), this check will fail. The same if value is 0 (zero), null, false. Failing, in this case, doesn’t mean that the property doesn’t exist. In fact, the property does exist and contains a value, but the value is falsy and so doesn’t pass this test.

Since ECMAScript 5 the base Object has the function hasOwnProperty(propertyName)
So you could try

```
if(myObject.hasOwnPorperty('attributeName')){
// do something
}
```

This function remembers us that the Objects has also prototype attributes that our object could inherit. For example if I write

```
myObject.anyAttribute='AnyValue';
var my1stObject = Object.create(myObject);
var my2ndObject = Object.create(myObject);
myObject.anyAttribute='AnotherValue';
console.log(my1stObject.anyAttribute);
console.log(my2ndObject.anyAttribute);
```

last two rows will print 'AnotherAttribute'.
In this case 1st and 2nd objects have not own property anyAttribute but they will use the prototipe one.
Different if you write

```
myObject.anyAttribute='AnyValue';
var my1stObject = Object.create(myObject);
var my2ndObject = Object.create(myObject);
my1stObject.anyAttribute='AnotherValue';
console.log(my1stObject.anyAttribute); //AnotherValue
console.log(my2ndObject.anyAttribute); //AnyValue
```

First object hasOwnProperty 'anyAttribute' because we set it.

At last, to be shure to check if property, proptotipe or own, really exists, you would like to use

```
if('anyProperty' in myObject){
//do something
}
```

I suggest you to read it better at this link:
https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/07/27/determining-if-an-object-property-exists/