# How to get nested objects in javascript by an string as a bracket notation?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want a method in javascript that gets a string as its arguments and return a value from a nested object like as:

```js
var obj = {
  place: {
    cuntry: 'Iran',
    city: 'Tehran',
    block: 68,
    info: {
     name :'Saeid',
      age: 22
    }
  }
};

function getValue(st) {
  // st: 'place[info][name]'
  return obj['place']['info']['name'] // or obj.place.info.name
}
```

Comment: The parameter `st` data format, can it be altered?

Comment: No the data format of `st` can't be changed :)

Comment: I can insert `"` after `[` and before `]` also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible solution for your use case:

```
function getValue(st, obj) {
    return st.replace(/\[([^\]]+)]/g, '.$1').split('.').reduce(function(o, p) { 
        return o[p];
    }, obj);
}

console.log( getValue('place[info][name]', obj) );  // "Saeid"
console.log( getValue('place.info.age', obj) );     // 22
```

Comment: Hi, can you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64911518/access-nested-object-with-n-level-deep-object-using-square-bracket-notation . :(

Comment: what about setValue(st, obj, value) ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you get your input in the form of "['a']['b']['c']"?

```
function getValue(st) {
  // st: "['place']['info']['name']"
  return eval("obj"+st);
}
```

You can apply transformation to any strings and get the result.

**EDIT:**

DO NOT Use Eval directly in your code base. Its evil!

Comment: `eval` will never be the best solution unfortunately.

Comment: thats true but the question is the most unusual  one I have seen

Comment: I've seen such before and even answered one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13719799/1249581. Funny but I even used that code in some projects at work.