# access nested object with "n" level deep object using square bracket notation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ej2-syncfusion

I want to take some config object to show some nested data.Here is the [demo code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ej2syncfusion-angular-grid-vox2ue?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

As it can be seen, `"customer.something"` is what I need to access. Now there could be 'N'level of nesting . The grid takes care of it using `field='customer.something'` . How to do the same using my `template`

```
<e-column field='customer.something' headerText='Other' editType='dropdownedit' [edit]='editParams' width=120>
```

Here is the HTML file:

```
<ejs-grid #Grid [dataSource]='data' allowSorting='true'>
    <e-columns>
        <ng-template #colTemplate ngFor let-column [ngForOf]="colList">
            <e-column [field]='column.field' [headerText]='column.header' textAlign='Right' width=90>
                <ng-template #template let-data>
                    {{data[column.field] |  currency:'EUR'}} <-- want to fix this line
                </ng-template>
            </e-column>
        </ng-template>
    </e-columns>
</ejs-grid>

<!-- <ejs-grid #Grid [dataSource]='data' allowSorting='true'>
    <e-columns>
        <e-column field='price' isPrimaryKey='true' headerText='Price' textAlign='Right' width=90></e-column>
        <e-column field='customer.something' headerText='Other' editType='dropdownedit' [edit]='editParams' width=120>
        </e-column>
    </e-columns>
</ejs-grid> -->
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing nested JavaScript objects and arrays by string path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arrays-by-string-path)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pipe to get the field value by the string path. Like this:

```
@Pipe({name: 'fieldFromPath'})
export class FieldFromPathPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(data: Object, property: string): Object {
    property = property.replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g, '.$1');
    property = property.replace(/^\./, '');
    var a = property.split('.');
    for (var i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; ++i) {
        var k = a[i];
        if (k in data) {
            data = data[k];
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
    return data;
  }
}
```

and on the template:

```
<ng-template #template let-data>
 {{data | fieldFromPath: column.field |  currency:'EUR'}}
</ng-template>
```

Here's how it would look:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ej2syncfusion-angular-grid-jqm2kz

PS: I got the function to get the property value from the string path from this stackoverflow answer: [Accessing nested JavaScript objects and arrays by string path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arrays-by-string-path)

There are other ways to get it, maybe some is better.