# Assigning nested values in (partially) undefined objects

Tags: javascript

Say I want to assign a value like this:

```
x.label1.label2.label3 = someValue;
// or equivalently:
x['label1']['label2']['label3'] = someValue;
```

This works as long as `x.label1.label2` is defined but runs into reference errors otherwise. Which makes sense of course. But is there an easy way to assign this anyway where it simply creates the necessary nested objects?

So for example, if `x` equals `{ label1: {}, otherLabel: 'otherValue' }` I want to update `x` to become `{ label1: { label2: { label3: someValue } }, otherLabel: otherValue }`

I think I might be able to write a function myself, but is there a language feature or standard library function that does this?

Comment: I am not aware of any such "deep assignment"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a language feature or standard library function that does this

No. You have to write your own function or use a library that provides such functionality.

Related: [How to set object property (of object property of..) given its string name in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13719593/218196)

Answer (score 1):

This is partially possible using the [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) class. You can wrap your object in a Proxy and override the `get` trap to create another copy of the same proxy when you access a nonexistent property. This lets you recursively create "deep" properties. An example:

```
let traps = {
    get: function (target, name) {
        if (!(name in target))
            target[name] = new Proxy({}, traps);

        return target[name];
    }
};

let x = new Proxy({}, traps);
```

Then you would use `x` like any object, except it has this special behavior:

```
x.label1.label2.label3 = 'foo';
```

which creates a nested hierarchy of objects. However, note that this will create an object even if you access a nonexistent property. Thus, you will have to use the `in` keyword to check if it really contains a given property.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should indeed use a custom function such as:

```js
function assignByPath(obj, path, value) {
  var field = path.split('>'),
      last = field.pop();

  field.reduce(
    function(node, f) {
      return node[f] = node[f] instanceof Object ? node[f] : {};
    }, obj
  )[last] = value;
}

var myObj = {};
assignByPath(myObj, 'label1>label2>label3', 'someValue');

console.log(myObj);
```

Theoretically, you could also override `Object.prototype`, which would allow you to do:

```
myObj.assignByPath('label1>label2>label3', 'someValue');
```

But I would not recommend that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.shift()`, `Object.assign()`, recursion

```js
var x = {
  label1: {},
  otherLabel: "otherValue"
};

var nestprops = (props, value, obj, o, curr = props.shift()) => props.length 
  ? nestprops(props, value, (Object.assign(obj, {[curr]: {}}) && obj[curr]), o) 
  : ((!value || value) && (obj[curr] = value) && o);

console.log(nestprops(["label1", "label2", "label3"], "someValue", x, x));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check length of **keys** inside `label1 object` if its equal to `0` then modify it to your desired **object**.

Here is a **snippet**, hope it helps.

```js
var obj = { label1: {}, otherLabel: 'otherValue' };

if(Object.keys(obj.label1).length == 0 ) {
    obj.label1 = { label2: { label3: "value3" } };
}
console.log(obj);
```