# How do I use an array of indices to alter a specific item in a multi-dimensional object of unknown depth?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Imagine I have an array, which looks like:

```
const x = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

I wish to use it in order to navigate an object that I don't know the structure of, like:

```
const y = {
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "c": {
                "d": "Value I require"
            }
        },
        "f": ["g", "h"]
    },
    "e": null
}
```

However, my issue is that I don't know how deep `y` will be, or how many indices are in the array `x`.  How do I do the following:

```
let someVariable = {"prefilled": "data"}
someVariable[x[0]][x[1]][x[2]][x[3]] = y[x[0]][x[1]][x[2]][x[3]]
```

In a way which is neither specific to the length of `x`, the depth of `y` (and also preferably isn't my current solution, which is a case statement upto a depth of 6)?  For this simplified case, `someVariable` should hopefully look as follows:

```
{
    "prefilled": "data",
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "c": {
                "d": "Value I require"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also a duplicate of [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6491463/218196)

Comment: @FelixKling Damnit, sorry about the duplicate.  I guess I just couldn't phrase the question in the right way for Google ;).

Comment: No worries, searching can be difficult :) I guess that's an even better one: [How to set object property (of object property of..) given its string name in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13719593/218196)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would either use a tool like Lodash's [`_.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get) or implement something similar that can navigate an object:

```
let _ = require('lodash');
const x = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
_.get(object, x.join('.'))
```

Comment: A great answer!  Especially considering I actually get my data in the format of "a.b.c.d" and turned it into an array for convenience.  Allows me to also do `_.set` to set the other object instance, as a note to future readers.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the array and walk the object.

```js
const getValue = (object, path) => path.reduce((o, k) => (o || {})[k], object),
      y = { a: { b: { c: { d: "Value I require" } }, f: ["g", "h"] }, e: null },
      x = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

console.log(getValue(y, x));
```