# Do arguments based on object property values not hold a reference?

Tags: javascript

I came across this question as I was building a recursive function to drill into objects. Given an object and path (as an Array of strings):

```
const path = ['path', 'to', 'nestedObj', 'someProp'];

const obj = {
  path: {
    to: {
      nestedObj: {
        someProp: 'someValue'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I came up with this solution:

```
function setValueFromPath(object, path, value) {
  let nestedObj = object[path[0]];
  const nextPath = path.slice(1, path.length);
  if(path.length > 1) {
    return setValueFromPath(nestedObj, nextPath, value);
  }
  nestedObj = value;
}
```

It didn't reassign the value to some prop however. To me this means the last line, in `nestedObj = value`, `nestedObj` is not holding a reference to the original obj.

So I did some fiddling and tried this:

```
function setValueFromPath(object, path, value) {
  let nestedObj = object[path[0]];
  const nextPath = path.slice(1, path.length);
  if(path.length > 2) {
    return setValueFromPath(nestedObj, nextPath, value);
  }
  nestedObj[path[1]] = value;
}
```

In this case this does mutate the original object(intended behavior). My question: Why does this `nestedObj` seemingly hold a reference to the original object but not the first in the first solution? I don't think it has anything to do with this being a recursive function. But I was a bit confused and was wondering if someone could shed some light.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set object property (of object property of..) given its string name in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719593/how-to-set-object-property-of-object-property-of-given-its-string-name-in-ja)

Comment: Making `nestedObj` point to a different object has no effect on what it used to point to.

Comment: I don't believe so, this question has more to do with references in memory

Comment: At the innermost level of recursion, you still have to `return` something.

Comment: isn't there implicit return of undefined? I mean the function works, thats not really what my question is about either 0.0

Comment: @Slaks doesn't `nestedObj` point to the reference in memory the property I want to change?

Comment: You actually need to set the last `property` of the object. Not the object itself

Comment: And well the variable holds the reference. When you override a reference, you rewrite the reference, not the obkect it is pointing to. By the way: `for(const sub of path) object = object[sub];`

Comment: that is definitely it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that when you set a reference to an object, the pointer to that object is passed through, but when you set a reference to a variable, it will create a new one.

Let me explain myself, in the first iterations of you function, you will copy the object to nestedObj

```
let nestedObj = object[path[0]]; // so nestedObj points to path, which is an object
```

But in the last iteration, you will simply copy the value of someProp to nestedObj (and since it is not an object, it will create a new place in memory to stock it, and thus only change that instance of the variable).

```
let nestedObj = object[path[0]]; // Here nested obj is a copy of someProp
```