# String to object in JavaScript , one object

Tags: javascript, string, object

I have a string as

```
string = "foo.call=45&doo.foo=20&foo.in=5";
```

now I need one object obj such that

```
obj = {"foo": {"call": "45"}} {"foo": {"call": "45","in":"5"},"doo": {"foo":20}}
```

How can I do this in JavaScript?
For one string = "foo.call=45"

```
function aaa(string){
    var aa = string.split('=')[0],
        bb = string.split('=')[1];
    function setValue(object, path, value) {
    var way = path.split('.'),
        last = way.pop();
    way.reduce((o, k) => o[k] = o[k] || {}, object)[last] = value;
    return object;
    }
    var object = JSON.stringify(setValue({}, aa, bb));
    console.log(object);    
}
```

Comment: This may help with part of your question: [How to set object property (of object property of..) given its string name in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719593/how-to-set-object-property-of-object-property-of-given-its-string-name-in-ja)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set object property (of object property of..) given its string name in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719593/how-to-set-object-property-of-object-property-of-given-its-string-name-in-ja)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the string by equal sign and take the left part as path to the value in an object.

```js
function setValue(object, path, value) {
    var way = path.split('.'),
        last = way.pop();

    way.reduce((o, k) => o[k] = o[k] || {}, object)[last] = value;
    return object;
}

function getObject(string, object = {}) {
    string
        .split('&')
        .forEach(s => setValue(object, ...s.split('=')));

    return object;
}

console.log(getObject('foo.test.rest.call=45'));
console.log(getObject('foo.call=45&doo.foo=20&foo.in=5'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks. If this is the case: string = "foo.call=45&doo.foo=20&foo.in=5" ?

Comment: @magnum888, you could split by `'&'` and take the same object for assigning.