# Is it possible to add dynamically named objects to JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, object

So I was reading the [dynamically named properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object), which is similar to what I am wanting to do.

I want to pass in an object to be referenced into my object type.

I have a variable in my object that I want to set.

```
template.format.bold = true;
```

I am wanting to pass in the object along with it's property into a function to set a value.

```
function setItem(item, value) {
    template[item] = value;
}
```

Then I want to be call the function:

```
setItem('format.bold', true);
```

How do I do this?

**Error received:**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'e' of undefined

Comment: The duplicate only tries to read a value for a given path. [How to set object property (of object property of..) given its string name in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719593/how-to-set-object-property-of-object-property-of-given-its-string-name-in-ja) creates properties defined by a given path.

Comment: I think for your case, you need to look at the function `ReadValue` posted by hamboy75, your case is using nested properties as format is a property of template and bold is a property of format