# How to interpolate a key based on a parameter and update its value in an object es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have

```
const abc = {
  main: {
    primary: 'initialPrimary',
    },
  buttons: {
    text: 'initialText',
  },
}
```

```
const updateAbc = (node, key, value) => {
return {updated abc}
}
```

So, if I call `updateAbc('main','primary','updatedPrimary')`, it should return updated abc object

```
{
  main: {
    primary: 'updatedPrimary',
   },
  buttons: {
    text: 'initialText',
  },
}
```

or when called `updateAbc('buttons','text','updatedText')`, it should return updated abc object with values

```
{
  main: {
    primary: 'initialPrimary',
  },
  buttons: {
    text: 'updatedText',
  },
}
```

It should update only for the value passed. How can it be done in es6?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set object property (of object property of..) given its string name in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719593/how-to-set-object-property-of-object-property-of-given-its-string-name-in-ja)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const abc = {
  main: {
    primary: 'initialPrimary',
    },
  buttons: {
    text: 'initialText',
  },
}

const updateAbc = (node, key, value) => {
  return {
     ...abc, 
    [node]: {
      [key]: value
    } 
  }
}
```

*Note that this won't check for non-existent nodes or keys as-is.*

You asked specifically for es6, so that's what I answered with. This works by spreading `abc` and then dynamically using `node` and `key` to provide the path to the updated value.

By using `Object.assign` you could achieve the same result by doing:

```
const updateAbc = (node, key, value) => {
  var copyAbc = Object.assign({},abc)
  copyAbc[node][key] = value
  return copyAbc
}
```

**But** that will fail and produce an error if given a non-existent `node` name