# Dynamically updating a JavaScript object from a string path

Tags: javascript, object, path

Im trying to figure out if its possible to update a JavaScript object, using a string as the path.

In the example below, I'm trying to figure out how I can update the first books price using 
`store>book>0>price` as my path.

I know I can access this by writing `data['store']['book'][0]['price']` but I need to be able to do this dynamically. Ive tried a few things but had no luck. Any Ideas?

***This needs to work for any depth , not a fixed depth***

---

**Data:**

```
 var data = { 
      "store": {
        "book": [ 
          { "category": "reference",
            "author": "Nigel Rees",
            "title": "Sayings of the Century",
            "price": 8.95
          },
          { "category": "fiction",
            "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
            "title": "Sword of Honour",
            "price": 12.99
          }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
          "color": "red",
          "price": 19.95
        }
      }
    }
var path = "store>book>0>price"
```

**Function:**

```
function updateObject(object, path, data) {
    var pathArray = path.split(">");
    // Some code here
} 
updateObject(data, path, "10.00");
```

---

**Update**

As felix pointed out the answer can be found here.
[Dynamic deep setting for a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842795/dynamic-deep-setting-for-a-javascript-object)

Here is a working example for my scenario
http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/Sq8j3/9/

Comment: @mplungjan: Not necessarily. It works with a `for` loop as well. Have a look at the linked question.

Comment: While the related question is very similar, it does not address the problem of updating the object

Comment: @Blowsie: You mean like the problem of assigning a value to a property? If not, what do you mean?

Comment: You are right. Those two do: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13719593/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/6842795/218196.

Comment: You deleted your comment, but still: Arrays are just objects, you can access both the same way, so it does not make a difference. Here is a fiddle, [applying this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6842900/218196) to your data: http://jsfiddle.net/Sq8j3/6/.

Comment: Why the downvote? I thought this was a good question. I've upvoted it but that it only brings it back to 0...

Comment: @guypursey thanks, I don't know why it was downvoted, okay the question was already on SO, but not with the words I searched on

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
function updateObject(object, newValue, path){

  var stack = path.split('>');

  while(stack.length>1){
    object = object[stack.shift()];
  }

  object[stack.shift()] = newValue;

}
```

Comment: works a charm thankyou http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/Sq8j3/11/

Comment: neat Like the duplicate (and my rewrite of it) but without testing for object existence. Still if data is known to work, a very compact version

Comment: very nice, good solution.

Comment: Fantastic solution. I have been wondering how to do this.

Comment: This is the best I have seen yet. I have made extensions for get, set and add as well: https://embed.plnkr.co/kwF83lMQtKb6Vb8aP8jt/

Comment: Is there any easy way to have this function create the path if it doesn't exist?

Comment: I found it helpful to make a copy of the path, `[ ...path ]`, to make sure I didn't accidentally change data - I'd think you'd usually want to avoid mutating that kind of data (as the the `shift()`s will)

Answer (score 3):

You want to update your method signature to accept the: object you're modifying, the path string, and the value you're assigning to the final path property.

```
function updateObject(data, path, value) {
        var pathArray = path.split(">");
        var pointer = data; // points to the current nested object
        for (var i = 0, len = pathArray.length; i < len; i++) {
            var path = pathArray[i];
            if (pointer.hasOwnProperty(path)) {
                if (i === len - 1) { // terminating condition
                    pointer[path] = value;
                } else {
                    pointer = pointer[path];
                }
            } else {
                // throw error or terminate. The path is incorrect
            }
        }
    }
```

Or recurse. Or use a [while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6491621/360705). But this is the general idea.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sq8j3/8/

Comment: thanks for your efforts, doesn't quite work for me .. http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/Sq8j3/

Comment: Fixed it: http://jsfiddle.net/Sq8j3/8/

Comment: This worked well for me!! Specially for updating multiple paths in a object! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's slightly confusing that you've called your object `data` but that `data` is also an argument of your function. I've changed the argument's name therefore to `newVal` in order to clear up this potential problem.

This loops through the path and constantly resets a variable called `e` which starts by pointing to the `data` object generally and gets more specific as we loop. At the end, you should have an almost reference to the exact property -- we use the last part of the path to set the new value.

```
function updateObject(newVal, path) {
    var pathArray = path.split(">"),
        i = 0,
        p = pathArray.length - 1, // one short of the full path
        e = data; // "import" object for changing (i.e., create local ref to it)
    for (i; i < p; i += 1) { // loop through path
        if (e.hasOwnProperty(pathArray[i])) { // check property exists
            e = e[pathArray[i]]; // update e reference point
        }
    }
    e[pathArray[i]] = newVal; // change the property at the location specified by path to the new value
};
```

You might need to add something to catch errors. I have put a check in with the `hasOwnProperty()` call but you might need something more elaborate than this.

**UPDATE**

Had made a silly mistake in the code before but it should be working now. As evidenced [here](http://jsfiddle.net/guypursey/Sq8j3/12/).

Comment: thanks for your efforts, doesn't quite work for me  http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/Sq8j3/2/

Comment: Thanks for acknowledging the efforts :-) I had made a couple of mistakes in my code which I've now corrected. Unfortunately, this still isn't quite right but you can see something is starting to happen... http://jsfiddle.net/Sq8j3/10/

Comment: @Blowsie Fixed now. I see you have a correct (and more concise) answer now anyway but I didn't like the idea of leaving erroneous code up ! :-)