# jQuery update JSON with string keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string

I have JSON data in array variable and I want to update some value in this array by string keys.
Here is what's my array look like:

```
{
    "all": [
        {
            "image":{
                "URL":"img/img1.jpeg",
                "font": "sfsdfsdf",
                "color": "sfsdfs"
            },
            "music": {
                "URL":"fsfsfd",
                "time": {
                    "start":"sfsdf",
                    "end":"qdqsd"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "image":{
                "URL":"img/img2.jpeg",
                "font": "sfsdfsdf",
                "color": "sfsdfs"
            },
            "music": {
                "URL":"fsfsfd",
                "time": {
                    "start":"sfsdf",
                    "end":"qdqsd"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a second array with the path splitted of the key I want to update like this:

```
var path = ["all", 0, "image", "font"]
```

For the moment I just loop `path` variable and search in my JSON data if the key exist.
But I have absolutly no idea how to update my JSON array without altering the schema of the array...

For example I want to replace `myArray[all][0][image][font]` value by "My Other Value"

The final goal is to have my JSON array updated and rewrite a JSON file.

**EDIT :**

I found the solution here : [Dynamically updating a JavaScript object from a string path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092912/dynamically-updating-a-javascript-object-from-a-string-path)

Answer (score 0):

First, it's worth noting that this has nothing to do with jQuery.

In any case, an easy way to do this is to use the [_.get()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get) function from [Lodash](https://lodash.com/). It does exactly what you are looking for.

This is also a pretty simple piece of code to write yourself, but Lodash has many other good and well-tested utility functions, so it's worth your while to get familiar with it. Here's a test:

```js
let data = {
    "all": [
        {
            "image":{
                "URL":"img/img1.jpeg",
                "font": "sfsdfsdf",
                "color": "sfsdfs"
            },
            "music": {
                "URL":"fsfsfd",
                "time": {
                    "start":"sfsdf",
                    "end":"qdqsd"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "image":{
                "URL":"img/img2.jpeg",
                "font": "sfsdfsdf",
                "color": "sfsdfs"
            },
            "music": {
                "URL":"fsfsfd",
                "time": {
                    "start":"sfsdf",
                    "end":"qdqsd"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
};

let path = [ "all", 0, "image", "font" ];

let value = _.get( data, path );

console.log( value );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: My goal isn't to get the value of my path I know how to do it. My goal is to update the key path and return the array `data` complete with the modification. Does Lodash can do that ?