# Change values of multidimensional array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

```js
var arr = [[],[],null,[[],[]],[[[]]]];
$( document ).ready(function() {
  
  
  
  addChild(arr, 'main');
  
  
  
});

function inscribe(numbers, value) {
    while(numbers.length>1){
      arr = arr[numbers.shift()];
    }

    arr[numbers.shift()] = value;
    
    addChild(arr, 'main');
    
  }
  
  function addChild(subarr, id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    var ul = document.createElement("ul");
    el.appendChild(ul);
    subarr.forEach(function(item, index){
      var node = document.createElement("div");
      var textnode = document.createTextNode(id + '-' + index);
      node.appendChild(textnode);
      node.id = id + '-' + index;
      ul.appendChild(node);
      if(item && item.length)
        addChild(item, node.id);
    })
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main"> </div>

<button onclick="inscribe([3,1], [[]])">inscribe([3,1], [[]])</button>
```

Let's suppose I have a nD array which its values is dynamically changing.
`let arr = [[],[],[[],[]],null,[]];`. I need a function which receives an array of numbers, and a value, to change that value of the main array.

```
/*
 * numbers: an array of integers which indicates which element of array should be set
 * value: the value that should be set
 */
inscribe(numbers, value) {
   // set value for desired position
}
```

For example if numbers are `[x,y,z]`, it should change `arr[x][y][z] = value`.
notice that we do not know the length of `numbers` array.
Any suggestion for implementing the function?

Comment: loop over numbers. Use bracket notation, set value on last index.

Comment: can you explain more please? @epascarello

Comment: Same thing as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092912/dynamically-updating-a-javascript-object-from-a-string-path

Comment: I did the same thing, it doesn't work the array

Comment: It does too.... it is no different. You have the array split up already. The string uses split to make the array....

Comment: just check the snippet @epascarello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use recursion to get/change the values;

```js
function inscribe(arr, path, value){
   if(path.length == 1){
      arr[path[0]] = value;
   }else{
      var next = path.shift();
      inscribe(arr[next], path, value);
   }
}
```