# VueJs directive two way binding

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, jquery-select2, vue-directives

I created a custom directive to handle select2 in VueJs. The code below works when I am binding a select to a data property in my viewmodel that is not a propert of an object within data.

Like this.userId but if it is bound to something like this.user.id, it would not update the value in my viewmodel data object.

```
Vue.directive('selected', {    
    bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {    
        var key = binding.expression;    
        var select = $(el);    

        select.select2();    
        vnode.context.$data[binding.expression] = select.val();    

        select.on('change', function () {    
            vnode.context.$data[binding.expression] = select.val();    
        });    
    },    
    update: function (el, binding, newVnode, oldVnode) {    
        var select = $(el);    
        select.val(binding.value).trigger('change');    
    }    
});

<select v-selected="userEditor.Id">
   <option v-for="user in users" v-bind:value="user.id" >
       {{ user.fullName}}
   </option>
</select>
```

Related fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/raime910/rHm4e/4/

Comment: Can you share live demo of this ?

Comment: Why are you using directive instead of custom Vue-component? IMHO, component-way is match simpler -- you will not need to use this hack `vnode.context.$data`, also you can use `created`, `mounted` hooks, etc. Couple weeks ago I implemented wrapper for some jquery plugin in Vue: first time I went directive-way -- soon it became too complicated, so I refactored to separate vue-component and now it is simple and works fine.

Comment: By the way, did you saw this native vue-component-library: http://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/ ? -- I used this for my project. It is already vue-component, so no wrapper needed.

Comment: Also, please mention this moment: you are using `v-for` for object without `:key`-attribute here: `<option v-for="user in users" v-bind:value="user.id" >`.  It should be like that: `<option v-for="user in users" v-bind:value="user.id"  :key="user.id">` (see this documentation: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key). In short - if you are iterating objects, and not primitive types -- you probably will have unexpected errors with Vue-reactivity. (I spent full work day to figure out same omission in my project).

Comment: On that note, it's compulsory in later versions of Vue to have the `:key` when using `v-for`

Comment: Hi Alex, we didn't want to stray away for the standard elements that HTML provides because our backend is a ASP.NET MVC Core backend that uses Razor to create the html. When you use a component didn't you have to use a custom tag <select2>...</select2> to get it to work? And we decided to not go with the TagHelper route in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: `>The code below works when I am binding a select to a data property in my viewmodel that is not a propert of an object within data.`
Not exactly. The problem is not in that you passing object. The problem that you passing non-existing object in that scope.
in this code: `<select v-selected="user.id"><option v-for="user in users"...` in part `v-selected="user.id"` there is no `user`-object, it is `undefined`. And `user` will burn later from `users`, inside `v-for="user in users"`
Just try `<select v-selected="users[0].id">`.

Comment: Sorry I was not being clear there. I am not referring to the user in the v-for here <select v-selected="user.id">. I am referring to an object within data. I've updated my code. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: As a suggestion to skip these challenges try this https://monterail.github.io/vue-multiselect/

Comment: You can use an HTML select element and set the `is` attribute to make it a select2 component. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you using 1st level `$data`'s-property, it accessing to `$data` object directly through `[]`-brackets

But you want to pass to `selected`-directive the path to nested object, so you should do something like this:

```
// source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6842900/8311719
function deepSet(obj, value, path) {
    var i;
    path = path.split('.');
    for (i = 0; i < path.length - 1; i++)
        obj = obj[path[i]];

    obj[path[i]] = value;
}

Vue.directive('selected', {    
bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {    
    var select = $(el);    

    select.select2();    
    deepSet(vnode.context.$data, select.val(), binding.expression);    

    select.on('change', function () {    
        deepSet(vnode.context.$data, select.val(), binding.expression);
    });    
},    
update: function (el, binding, newVnode, oldVnode) {    
    var select = $(el);    
    select.val(binding.value).trigger('change');    
}    
});

<select v-selected="userEditor.Id">
<option v-for="user in users" v-bind:value="user.id" >
   {{ user.fullName}}
</option>
</select>
```

## Description:

Suppose we have two `$data`'s props: `valOrObjectWithoutNesting` and `objLvl1`:

```
data: function(){
  return{
    valOrObjectWithoutNesting: 'let it be some string',
    objLvl1:{
      objLvl2:{
        objLvl3:{
          objField: 'primitive string'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Variant with 1st level $data's-property:

```
<select v-selected="valOrObjectWithoutNesting">

// Now this code:
vnode.context.$data[binding.expression] = select.val();
// Equals to: 
vnode.context.$data['valOrObjectWithoutNesting'] = select.val();
```

Variant with 4th level $data's-property:

```
<select v-selected="objLvl1.objLvl2.objLvl3.objField">

// Now this code:
vnode.context.$data[binding.expression] = select.val();
// Equals to: 
vnode.context.$data['objLvl1.objLvl2.objLvl3.objField'] = select.val(); // error here
```

So the `deepSet` function in my code above "converting" `$data['objLvl1.objLvl2.objLvl3.objField']` to `$data['objLvl1']['objLvl2']['objLvl3']['objField']`.

As you see, as I mentioned in comments to your question, when you want make select2-wrapper more customisable, the directive-way much more complicated, than separate component-way. In component, you would pass as much configuration props and event subscriptions as you want, you would avoid doing side mutations like `vnode.context.$data[binding.expression]` and your code would become more understandable and simpler for further support.

Answer (score 0):

A custom directive is perfectly fine, except use the `inserted`hook instead of `bind`.  Adapted from [Vue Wrapper Component Example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html).

To bind to an object property, the simplest way is to wrap it in a computed setter [Computed Setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) and bind to that.

Note, 'deep setting' does not appear to work. The problem is one of change detection, which the computed setter overcomes. (Note that the `on('change'` function is jQuery not Vue.)

```js
console.clear()

Vue.directive('selected', {
  inserted: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    var select = $(el);
    select
      .select2()
      .val(binding.value)
      .trigger('change')
      .on('change', function () {
        if (vnode.context[binding.expression]) {
          vnode.context[binding.expression] = select.val();     
        }
      })
    },
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#my-app',
  computed: {
    selectedValue: {
      get: function() { return this.myObj.type },
      set: function (value) { this.myObj.type = value }
    }
  },
  data: {
    selectedVal: 0,
    myObj: { type: 3 },
    opts: [{
      id: 1,
      text: 'Test 1'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      text: 'Test 2'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      text: 'Test 3'
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.4/vue.js"></script>

<div id="my-app">
  <div>
    <label for="example">Test dropdown list ({{ myObj.type }})</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select id="example" style="width: 300px" v-selected="selectedValue">
      <option v-for="(opt,index) in opts" :value="opt.id" :key="index">
        {{ opt.text }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```